# Window separated in different workspace

Tags: workspaces

I am a newbie in ubuntu.. when I was working with qgis I lost my status bar that located in bottom of the window.. After, googling, I found that the status bar moved to different workspace.. Maximize button in the window was disabbled and I cann't restore my window to one workspace only. How to restore my whole qgis window only in one workspace? 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Screenshot may help to understand the real situation. Please edit your question and add it.

Answer (score 1):

Actually my problem is about qgis window that larger than the workspace... I can fix this issue by deleting .qgis2 folder in /home/username. After deleted this folder, a new folder with same name will be created when starting qgis. I lost my plugin after doing this, but this really fix the issue.